# Performance: Queues vs Topics

Tags: azureservicebus

In a scenario of a queue and a message receiver vs a topic and a single subscriber, what will perform better?

Answer (score 0):

It depends, right?
What's the load of messages your system will experience? What your scenario? What is your **requirement**?

Obviously when we're talking about high volume and complex filters for subscriptions, topics with subscriptions might slightly perform less than a streight queue. But you use the right approach for a problem. Queues won't allow a pub/sub implementation like topics and subscriptions do.

Comment: Actually, if you can imagine a controlled test that does not depend on anything. Where all the variables are normalized, message shape, environment, one to one, pound for pound, there must exist an empirical throughput unit measure.

Comment: Frankly, I don't understand what are you after. If performance is so critical, you might be even looking at the wrong technology 
W/o understanding the problem at hand,  the question is too vague.

Comment: Sean, actually I am a messaging expert, and I have very deep understanding of MOA and SB's and have no doubt about my choice of architecture.  There need not be a context for setting the stage for this question.  Analogous to the need for context in the question of 2+2.